# DIVs float in a non-linear way

Tags: html, css

have a css float problem that i'm not sure how to fix or best way to fix and can't seem to find anything in searches. I have a variable amount of items to show inside a div, using a css float left on all the inner boxes (1, 2, and 3 in pic) but the float breaks with variable lines of text. the developer outlines show that because box 1 is larger that box 2, box 3 doesn't float flush left like box 1 which screws up the flow. how do i keep the vertical height of box 1 and box 2 but make box 3 float left where it should be? Doing a float: right; does the same thing but just pushes 3 to the left is div 2 is larger than div 1

This is just an example, there could be a variable number of rows and columns so just doing an Nth div css rule won't work. (the containing div is a variable width based on a few conditions including responsive design)

Almost like i have to have a variable buffer at the bottom of each item in a row to match the height of the tallest one. I also don't want to use a min-height as on rows where the divs are the same height will result in extra white space where there shouldn't be. How would i get the tallest element in a row if the number of columns are variable?

A possible solution is to use the empty clearing div trick but again how do I get the number of divs in a row when columns are variable? I tried to force a nth child::after thing in the example but it didn't work

```
.item:nth-child(2)::after {
    clear: both;
}
```

Search didn't show anything that works so if anyone has a post that does please let me know.

also have to stick with CSS2 if at all possible due to a bunch of users using older browsers that don't use CSS3

[image: float problem]

Comment: Can you include a snippet with html and css? I'll be glad to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to use `display:inline-block` for the figures rather than `float:left`.

```css
.figure {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 2px 1em;
  border:1px solid grey;
}

.figcaption {
  margin:1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
  <div class="figure">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="#">
    <div class="figcaption">
      Line 1<br/>Line 2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="figure">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="#">
    <div class="figcaption">
      Line 1
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="figure">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="#">
    <div class="figcaption">
      Line 1<br/>Line 2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked like a charm, had to add a vertical-align: top to keep them all aligned properly :). The flex solutions did work too but unfortunately enough users are still using an old enough browser that it doesn't work. and the nth-child(3) solution didn't work at all for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear:both the 3rd element actually in this case.
See solution below.

```css
img {
  width:50%;
  float:left;
} 
img:nth-child(3) {
    clear: both;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x160">
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
```

If you got some complex example please provide jsfiddle.

Comment: This was my first solution but it didn't work and not sure why. I tried both the nth-child(3) and nth-child(2)::after but neither worked. But also leads to the other problem of variable length columns, it's not going to be just 2 every time :(

Answer (score 0):

that's because your `<div>`s are styled with "float" and 3rd div has floated to 1st, because 1st is taller than others.

Possible solutions (not including the hardcoding - it's like a deadly sin):

1. Give equal height to each item in a set

```css
.float {
  background-color: #f90;
  float: left;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  width: calc(50% - 20px);
}
```

```html
<div class="float">float 1</div>
<div class="float">float 2</div>
<div class="float">float 3</div>
```

2. Use different approach, such as flexbox

```css
.wrapper {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex {
  background-color: #f90;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  width: calc(50% - 20px);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="flex" style="height: 120px;">flex 1</div>
  <div class="flex">flex 2</div>
  <div class="flex">flex 3</div>
</div>
```