# How to turn 4 pictures (with captions) in a row into a 2x2 grid after resize

Tags: html, css, media-queries

Edit codepen from Bastian: https://codepen.io/Bastian2001/pen/GRoGrrY

I've made a web page with 4 tall pictures in a row with captions underneath. I'm trying to get the the images to stack into a 2x2 square grid with captions, after the window width has been decreased to a certain px size.

I tried to set the image blocks to take up 50% of the width but I'm pretty sure I'm not using that correctly as the positions mess up pretty badly.

```
@media (max-width: 1020px) {

    .imgServicesBlock {
        width: 50%;
}
```

The captions widths and heights also go crazy and don't line up properly at certain window sizes. I tried using the @media to edit the font size which didn't seem to work either.

Lastly, at full screen the images aren't lining up horizontally when certain captions have more text lines.

Apologies for all the questions and roughness of the code.

Thanks in advance for any help!

CSS

```
 * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: 'Open Sans';
        /*text-transform: uppercase;*/
    }
    html {
        font-size: 62.5%;
        
    }
    body {
        color: black;
        letter-spacing: .18em;
        min-width: 400px;
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center center;  
    }
    
    
    /* This section is for the services page */
    
    .gmSectionText {
        text-align:center;
        width: 20vw;
        Height: 80px;
        max-height: 450px;
        max-width: 230px;   
        color:#808080
        padding-bottom: 10px;
        padding-top: 10px;
        font-size: 15px;
        background-color: white;
        
    }
    
    .propSectionText {
        text-align:center;
        width: 20vw;
        Height: 80px;
        max-height: 450px;
        max-width: 230px;   
        color:#808080
        padding-bottom: 10px;
        padding-top: 10px;
        font-size: 15px;
        background-color: white;
    }
    
    .fluidSectionText {
        text-align:center;
        width: 20vw;
        Height: 80px;
        max-height: 450px;
        max-width: 230px;   
        color:#808080
        padding-bottom: 10px;
        padding-top: 10px;
        font-size: 15px;
        background-color: white;
    }
    
    .sandSectionText {
        text-align:center;
        width: 20vw;
        Height: 80px;
        max-height: 450px;
        max-width: 230px;   
        color:#808080
        padding-bottom: 10px;
        padding-top: 10px;
        font-size: 15px;
        background-color: white;
    }
    
    .imgServicesContainer {
        text-align:center;
        margin-top: 30px;
        display: inline;
    }
    
    .imgServicesBlock {
        width: 20vw;
        Height: 35vw;
        /*max-height: 500px;*/
        /*max-width: 300px;*/
        max-height: 450px;
        max-width: 220px;
        display: inline-block;
        margin-right: 22px;
        margin-left: 22px;
        object-fit: cover;
        background-color:red;
        transition: transform .2s;
    }
    
    .imgServicesBlock:hover {
      -ms-transform: scale(1.1); /* IE 9 */
      -webkit-transform: scale(1.1); /* Safari 3-8 */
      transform: scale(1.1); 
    }
    
    
    .imgServices {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: white;
        border-width: 5px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        object-fit: cover;
    }
    
    
    section { 
        text-align: center;
    }
    h2 {
        font-size: 13px;
        
    }
    
    h2 a{
        padding: 8 8 8 8px;
        float: left;
        color: white;
        background-color: red;
        font-family: 'Open Sans';
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    
    h3 {
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 60px;
        color: white;
    }
   
    
    /*This bit removes the cakes in the name if the window is too small"*/
    
    @media (max-width: 700px) {
    
      .edit-name{
        display: none;
      }
      
    }
    
    /*Removes the tel and email when window is narrow */
    
    @media (max-width: 1230px) {
    
      .narrow-hide{
        display: none;
        
      }
      
    }
    
    @media (max-width: 1020px) {
    
        .imgServicesBlock {
            width: 50%;
            Height: 35vw;       
            max-height: 200px;
            max-width: 200px;
            display: inline-block;
            margin-right: 22px;
            margin-left: 22px;
            object-fit: cover;
            transition: transform .2s;
            font-size: 5px;
        }
      
    }
    
    @media (max-width: 420px) {
    
        .imgServicesBlock {
            width: 50%;
            Height: 35vw;       
            max-height: 20px;
            max-width: 20px;
            display: inline-block;
            margin-right: 11px;
            margin-left: 11px;
            object-fit: cover;
            transition: transform .2s;
            font-size: 3px;
        }
        
        .propSectionText {
        font-size: 3px;
        }
      
    }
```

HTML

```
<div id="fullpage">
  <section class="vertical-scrolling" style="background-color: #f5f5f5";>
    <h3 style="display:block; margin-top: 50px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; margin-bottom: 20px; overflow-wrap: anywhere; width: 690px; color:#808080">OUR SERVICES</h3>
    <p style="color:#808080; margin-bottom:40px; font-size: 25px; word-wrap: break-word;">Click on the images below to learn more about our services<p> 
    <div class="imgServicesContainer">
        <div class="imgServicesBlock">
            <a href="https://www.google.com/" style="color:#808080">
            <img class="imgServices" src="..\Website Design Pics\Colour_Block.jpg" alt="blue">
            <div class="gmSectionText">
                <p>blah blah here here and you</p>
            </div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="imgServicesBlock">
            <a href="https://www.google.com/" style="color:#808080">
            <img class="imgServices" src="..\Website Design Pics\Colour_Block.jpg" alt="blue">
            <div class="propSectionText">
                <p>words and things are good to type to fill in the silence</p>
            </div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="imgServicesBlock">
            <a href="https://www.google.com/" style="color:#808080">
            <img class="imgServices" src="..\Website Design Pics\Colour_Block.jpg" alt="blue">
            <div class="fluidSectionText">
                <p>dogs are great to walk and pet. Awesome! I have 4 and also a parrot.</p>
            </div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="imgServicesBlock" style="margin-right: 50px;">  
            <a href="https://www.google.com/" style="color:#808080">
            <img class="imgServices" src="..\Website Design Pics\Colour_Block.jpg" alt="blue">
            <div class="sandSectionText">
                <p>hi and there text to sample</p>
            </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

!!!!Edit codepen from Bastian: https://codepen.io/Bastian2001/pen/GRoGrrY

Comment: Decluttered codepen: [here](https://codepen.io/Bastian2001/pen/GRoGrrY). Gonna try to fix it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

working example of what you are trying to achieve: https://codepen.io/Bastian2001/pen/qBbKRXV

CSS grid can help ([this question of mine from a couple of years ago might help you ;)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47237948/how-can-i-make-four-responsove-children-that-change-to-a-2-by-2-grid-when-making))

Inside your media query you would then have to set the parent's `grid-template-column` property to 2 (with the value outside the media query being 4), allowing this kind of behaviour that you are after.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @Paulie_D I'd say the first paragraph is a comment, but the second and third are definitely not. And the first paragraph is necessary because my answer just cannot be precise without an example

Comment: I am using a grid for another web page of mine which I am having separate issues atm (tldr: overflow stuff, things going off screen and misalignment etc). I will try this though if I can't fix it without a grid.

Comment: https://codepen.io/Bastian2001/pen/qBbKRXV @Ribeye what do you think of this?

Comment: Thanks for this! It's very close to what I'm after. I'll try work off this to fix the 4th box which appears to be too compressed and try and fix the captions which are still overlapping/not lining up. If I can get it then I will update this.

Comment: as for the captions not lining up, try to use `vertical-align` as a fix

Comment: I managed to get the captions fixed thanks to your solution. I was setting the image to fill 100% of the parent and it was pushing the captions out and thus overlapping. Really appreciate all your help!